# FBRequestConnection is very glitchy 400 error

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk

I get an `Error: HTTP status code: 400`

```
- (void)openSession
{
    [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:nil
                                       allowLoginUI:YES
                                  completionHandler:
     ^(FBSession *session,
       FBSessionState state, NSError *error) {
         [self sessionStateChanged:session state:state error:error];
     }];    

    [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"me" parameters:nil HTTPMethod:@"GET" completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"result %@",result);
    }];
}
```

This works sometimes and at other times I get this status code. Is there a more safer/less glitchy method to get a user's Facebook Graph data (username, name, fb_id)?

Comment: This should not actually happen if you do the implementation correctly. Can you provide a more detailed stacktrace when u catch the error? Also try looking at our sample code as part of the SDK for examples on how to implement.

Comment: I have added some context to the code. Basically I want to get the username, name, fb_id, so I did it this way, but it is still glitchy? I have tried other methods from your API and they didn't work either

Comment: [[FBRequest requestForMe] startWithCompletionHandler:
     ^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
       NSDictionary<FBGraphUser> *user,
       NSError *error) {}];

Comment: FBRequestConnection* conn = [[FBRequestConnection alloc] init];
    [conn addRequest:[FBRequest requestForMe] completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, NSDictionary<FBGraphUser> *me, NSError *error) {}];

Comment: ^These are some of the methods I had tried

Comment: Also, I have tried these in the AppDelegate and tried them in another view controller. I hope that's enough info to help me. Thank so much in advance. :)

Comment: @shireesh-asthana  Can you please look at my solution below. What do you think of it? Shouldn't Facebook's documentation be more clearer in regards to this. The name of the openSession method is kind of counter-intuitive, don't you think? Looking forward to your feedback in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

The error was - it was at the end of the `openSession` method. It should have been placed in the following method and case

```
- (void)sessionStateChanged:(FBSession *)session
                      state:(FBSessionState) state
                      error:(NSError *)error
{
    switch (state) {
        case FBSessionStateOpen: {
             //My code should have been placed here
    }
}
```

I assumed that by the end of the `openSession` method the session would be open (**common sense, eh!**) but I was wrong. The `openSession` just calls the *FB dialog - would you like to authorize this app?*

What I actually wanted was the **sessionStateChanged method - case (FBSessionStateOpen)** - this *gets called only after you click the okay button to the FB dialog that asks for authorization*.

I hope this clarifies the situation for any other people who have this issue.